# mysql distinct multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to get distinct rows for each column in rowset in MySQL.  These are sample tables:
system table:

```
jcn system
1   server
1   workstation
```

issue table:

```
jcn   issue
1     "not working"
```

area table:

```
jcn   area
1     102
1     103
1     104
```

I want the result to be:

```
system        area
server        102
workstation   103
              104
```

Is this possible.  I would use 2 queries, however I am putting it in a table in PHP, and want the table to look this way.
The result is always:

```
system       area
server       102
server       103
server       104
workstation  102
workstation  103
workstation  104
```

This result is from using

```
SELECT system, area FROM issues JOIN system USING (jcn) CROSS JOIN area USING (jcn) WHERE issues.jcn = 1
```

Comment: What is 'jcn' and why is it always '1'?

Comment: What makes number 102 go with server and not workstation? They all have the same ids.

Comment: jcn is the primary key in the issues table.  it is the control number for all issues.  There are many issues.  this is only 1 issue, which is "not working".  The system it affects is workstation and server, and the area it affects is 102, 103, and 104.  The table looks messy, the way it is

Comment: But why the expected result only has server with area 102? should be the three areas isn't it? and same for workstation And wich has the area 104 in your expected result? there's no system name in left side, please explain.

Comment: The area and system are not correlated. They are two different things that are affected by the issue. I just want it to display like this on a table using php. Should I just use two different queries and two different tables instead of trying to get this result with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of what you are trying to do...

It doesn't seem like you are trying to "pair" the systems and areas... it seems to me like you are trying to get all the possible values for "system" and all the possible values for "area" independently.

Therefore, if this assumption is correct, you could do it in 2 queries (one selecting "DISTINCT(system)" and the other selecting "DISTINCT(area)") and fetching them in 2 different arrays. If you wish the results to be merged into 1 array (like the example you gave), you could use array_combine (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

You could also keep the query you actually have, and fetch the result in 2 different arrays using the keys to make sure you get the "distinct" values:

```
$my_systems = array();
$my_area = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch()) { // or whatever method that lets you fetch your query row by row
   $my_systems[$row['system']] = $row['system'];
   $my_areas[$row['area']] = $row['area'];
}
$merged = array_combine(array_values($my_systems), array_values($my_areas)); // if you really need this in 1 merged array.
```

Please note that doing this in only 1 query would result in the number of rows being the result of count(distinct(system)) * count(distinct(area)). Using 2 separate queries is probably preferable.

Comment: Thanks, I am not trying to "pair" the results, but thought it was possible in one query. Thank you.